# Plotting Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization

How can I plot the logistic regression? I would like to plot the dependent variable on the y-axis and independent on the x. I called the coefficients and got an output, so no errors on the script.

Here's the data for the independent variable (SupPres):

```
#Set the range for water supply pressure
SupPres <- c(20:120)
#Create a normal distribution for water supply pressure
SupPres <- rnorm(3000, mean=70, sd=25)
```

Logistic regression and creating y-variable:

```
#Create logistic regression
z=1+2*NozHosUn+3*SupPres+4*PlaceSet+5*Hrs4+6*WatTemp
z <- (z-mean(z))/sd(z)
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))
y <- rbinom(3000,1,pr)
DishWa=data.frame(y=y, NozHosUn=NozHosUn,SupPres=SupPres,
               PlaceSet=PlaceSet,Hrs4=Hrs4,WatTemp=WatTemp)
glm(y~NozHosUn+SupPres+PlaceSet+Hrs4+WatTemp, data=DishWa, 
    family=binomial)
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution that takes up a suggestion in Michael J. Crawley's excellent book "Statistics: an introduction using R" is the following code:

```
attach(mtcars);
model <- glm(formula = am ~ hp + wt, family = binomial);
print(summary(model));
model.h <- glm(formula = am ~ hp, family = binomial);
model.w <- glm(formula = am ~ wt, family = binomial);
op <- par(mfrow = c(1,2));
xv <- seq(0, 350, 1);
yv <- predict(model.h, list(hp = xv), type = "response");
hp.intervals <- cut(hp, 3);
plot(hp, am);
lines(xv, yv);
points(hp,fitted(model.h),pch=20);
am.mean.proportion <- tapply(am, hp.intervals, sum)[[2]] / table(hp.intervals)[[2]];
am.mean.proportion.sd <- sqrt(am.mean.proportion * abs(tapply(am, hp.intervals, sum)[[3]] - tapply(am, hp.intervals, sum)[[1]]) / table(hp.intervals)[[2]]);
points(median(hp), am.mean.proportion, pch = 16);
lines(c(median(hp), median(hp)), c(am.mean.proportion - am.mean.proportion.sd, am.mean.proportion + am.mean.proportion.sd));
xv <- seq(0, 6, 0.01);
yv <- predict(model.w, list(wt = xv), type = "response");
wt.intervals <- cut(wt, 3);
plot(wt, am);
lines(xv, yv);
points(wt,fitted(model.w),pch=20);
am.mean.proportion <- tapply(am, wt.intervals, sum)[[2]] / table(wt.intervals)[[2]];
am.mean.proportion.sd <- sqrt(am.mean.proportion * abs(tapply(am, wt.intervals, sum)[[3]] - tapply(am, wt.intervals, sum)[[1]]) / table(wt.intervals)[[2]]);
points(median(wt), am.mean.proportion, pch = 16);
lines(c(median(wt), median(wt)), c(am.mean.proportion - am.mean.proportion.sd, am.mean.proportion + am.mean.proportion.sd));
detach(mtcars);
par(op);
```

In addition to the standard glm plot it contains an indicator for the fit of the central third to the data. It shows that the fit to *hp* is poor while that to *wt* is rather good.

[image: Example output]

The example uses R's built-in "cars" dataset.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to plot the results of logistic regression. See https://sites.google.com/site/daishizuka/toolkits/plotting-logistic-regression-in-r and [Plot two curves in logistic regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258708/plot-two-curves-in-logistic-regression-in-r) for explanations and examples in R.

Comment: Can you encapsulate the code here to make this answer whole?