# looping logistic regression row wise in R

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, glm

I'm trying to run logistic regression analyses for each row from R1 to R6 against C1 row of dataframe "dat"

```
Input data frame

dat <- data.frame(list(X1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), X2 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), X3 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), X4 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), X5 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), X6 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), X7 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), X8 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X9 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X10 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X11 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), X12 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ), X13 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), X14 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), X15 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), X16 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), X17 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X18 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X19 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X20 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X21 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), X22 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X23 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X24 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X25 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X26 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), X27 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X28 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X29 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), X30 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)),  row.names = c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "C1"))

logistic regression analyses

    R1 <- glm(r1 ~ C1, data=dat, family=binomial); coef(summary(R1))[,2] 
    R2 <- glm(r2 ~ C1, data=dat, family=binomial); coef(summary(R2))[,2] 
    R3 <- glm(r3 ~ C1, data=dat, family=binomial); coef(summary(R3))[,2] 
    R4 <- glm(r4 ~ C1, data=dat, family=binomial); coef(summary(R4))[,2] 
    R5 <- glm(r5 ~ C1, data=dat, family=binomial); coef(summary(R5))[,2] 
    R6 <- glm(r6 ~ C1, data=dat, family=binomial); coef(summary(R6))[,2]
```

The real data have 6000 row so it is not possible to do one by one row against C1.

Is there is a way to do it in loop where glm is calculated for each row from R1 to R6 against C1 and extract the output into a new column?

Comment: 1. your example code above does not run, which is clear because the formula expects column names and r1 and C1 are row names.

Comment: 2. if I‘m not mistaken you can‘t run regressions with single rows, because you have less observations than parameters to estimate or in other words, if you are looking at a single row, there are only constants, nothing that varies. So please clarify what you actually want to do.

Comment: the row called `C1` has only zero. that's why my solution wouldn't work but you can apply it if the question includes just a dummy data.

Comment: @deschen Thank you dear, actually I want to run logistic regression and I followed the example from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258708/plot-two-curves-in-logistic-regression-in-r

Comment: @deschen Yes it was by column and if it is not possible to run row-wise then can we transpose the data. and run it column-wise.

Comment: @SametSökel Dear actually I have binary data where one is a single categorical variable (like man) and the other one have two categorical variables (response). What kind of stat method would be better to check if data have more 0 or 1 kinds of response with single gender?

Comment: @gupta ok then, check my solution

Comment: @SametSökel Thank I am checking it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

independent_var <- 'C1'
dependent_vars <- setdiff(rownames(dat),independent_var)
compare <- NULL

for(i in dependent_vars){
    modelname <- toupper(i)
    
    filtered_data <- dat %>%
    t %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    select(all_of(c(i,'C1')))
    
    eval(parse(text=sprintf('%s <- glm(%s ~ %s,data=filtered_data,family=binomial)',modelname,i,independent_var)))
    eval(parse(text=sprintf('newrow <- data.frame(model="%s",coef=as.numeric(%s$coefficients[-2]))',modelname,modelname)))
    compare <- rbind(compare,newrow)
}

compare
```

**output;**

```
  model   coef
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 R1     0.405
2 R2    25.6  
3 R3    -0.134
4 R4    -0.405
5 R5     2.64 
6 R6    -1.01
```

Comment: I am checking it and get back to you shortly. Thank you for your help dear :)

Comment: Dear, it is running without error but not able to get output. This may be silly question but actually, I am a beginner and not able to get output. Please let me know how to get output of each dependent_vars with name like r1, r2 etc. Thanks

Comment: @gupta check my updated answer, it serves an output.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done for any number of lines. First, however, a small note. In your data, row `C1` contained all the values `0`. This, of course, was not suitable for the `glm` function. So I had to edit the `C1` line a bit.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(list(X1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), X2 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), X3 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), X4 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), X5 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), X6 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), X7 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), X8 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X9 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X10 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X11 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), X12 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ), X13 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), X14 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), X15 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), X16 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), X17 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X18 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X19 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X20 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X21 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), X22 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X23 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), X24 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X25 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X26 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), X27 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X28 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), X29 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), X30 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)),  row.names = c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "C1"))
```

output

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30
r1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1
r2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
r3  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
r4  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
r5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
r6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
C1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Then I split your data into rows `r` and row `C1`.

```
dfR = dat %>% as_tibble() %>% slice_head(n=nrow(.)-1) 
dfC = dat %>% as_tibble() %>% slice_tail()
```

output dfR

```
# A tibble: 6 x 30
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10   X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16   X17   X18   X19   X20   X21
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
3     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     0
4     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
5     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
6     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ... with 9 more variables: X22 <dbl>, X23 <dbl>, X24 <dbl>, X25 <dbl>, X26 <dbl>, X27 <dbl>, X28 <dbl>, X29 <dbl>, X30 <dbl>
```

output dfC

```
# A tibble: 1 x 30
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10   X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16   X17   X18   X19   X20   X21
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ... with 9 more variables: X22 <dbl>, X23 <dbl>, X24 <dbl>, X25 <dbl>, X26 <dbl>, X27 <dbl>, X28 <dbl>, X29 <dbl>, X30 <dbl>
```

Next, I have prepared four simple functions. `fGetRowValue` returns a vector with the values of one row. `fGetData` creates a `tibble` with two variables `x` and `C` where `x` is the value of a single row and `C` is of course the values from your `C1` row. `fglm` returns my model and `fCoef` returns `tibble` containing the coefficients from the model.

```
fGetRowValue = function(data) data %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% pull(value)

fGetData = function(dataR, dataC) tibble(
  x = fGetRowValue(dataR),
  C = fGetRowValue(dataC)
)

fglm = function(data) glm(x~C, binomial, data)

fCoef = function(model) tibble(
  Intercept = coef(model)[1],
  C = coef(model)[2]
)
```

Now is the time for the proper calculations.

```
dfR %>%  mutate(row = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  group_by(row) %>% 
  nest() %>%   #1
  group_modify(~fGetData(.x$data[[1]], dfC)) %>% #2
  nest() %>% #3
  mutate(model = map(data, ~fglm(.x))) %>% #4
  mutate(Ceof = map(model, ~fCoef(.x))) %>% #5
  unnest(Ceof)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   row [6]
    row data              model  Intercept        C
  <int> <list>            <list>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>     0.241   1.15e+0
2     2 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>    25.6    -1.98e-9
3     3 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>     0.0800 -1.47e+0
4     4 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>    -0.754   2.14e+0
5     5 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>     2.44    1.71e+1
6     6 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>    -1.39    1.79e+0
```

As the way I do my calculations can be a little confusing let me describe it year by year (see comment numbers).

After step 1, we receive the data in this form

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   row [6]
    row data             
  <int> <list>           
1     1 <tibble [1 x 30]>
2     2 <tibble [1 x 30]>
3     3 <tibble [1 x 30]>
4     4 <tibble [1 x 30]>
5     5 <tibble [1 x 30]>
6     6 <tibble [1 x 30]>
```

Variables data holds a `tibble` list with values on one row.

After step two, we have it as it is

```
# A tibble: 180 x 3
# Groups:   row [6]
     row     x     C
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1
 2     1     1     1
 3     1     1     1
 4     1     1     0
 5     1     0     0
 6     1     1     0
 7     1     0     0
 8     1     0     0
 9     1     0     0
10     1     1     0
# ... with 170 more rows
```

We roll it back up in step three

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   row [6]
    row data             
  <int> <list>           
1     1 <tibble [30 x 2]>
2     2 <tibble [30 x 2]>
3     3 <tibble [30 x 2]>
4     4 <tibble [30 x 2]>
5     5 <tibble [30 x 2]>
6     6 <tibble [30 x 2]>
```

Then in step four we complete our `tibble` with a variable containing the list of `glm` models.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   row [6]
    row data              model 
  <int> <list>            <list>
1     1 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm> 
2     2 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm> 
3     3 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm> 
4     4 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm> 
5     5 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm> 
6     6 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>
```

We have already taken the last step, which is to download the coefficients from our models.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   row [6]
    row data              model  Ceof            
  <int> <list>            <list> <list>          
1     1 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
2     2 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
3     3 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
4     4 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
5     5 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
6     6 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>  <tibble [1 x 2]>
```

Now all you need to do is `unnest` and we have the result you want.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   row [6]
    row data              model  Intercept        C
  <int> <list>            <list>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>     0.241   1.15e+0
2     2 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>    25.6    -1.98e-9
3     3 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>     0.0800 -1.47e+0
4     4 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>    -0.754   2.14e+0
5     5 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>     2.44    1.71e+1
6     6 <tibble [30 x 2]> <glm>    -1.39    1.79e+0
```

Note that by the way, all the models and the data used for their construction have been preserved. You can use it freely for further calculations.

Comment: I don't think manipulating data in this way is a bit unhealthy. `set.seed(1453); df <- data.frame(a=sample(c(0,1),200,replace = T),b=rep(0,200)); glm(a~b,data=df,family=binomial)` works enough to get intercept when dependent var is consisting only zeros.

Comment: @Marek Dear you had done a wonderful job. It rarely to see such a long and beautiful post. As a beginner, I can learn manything from it. In my free time, I will go through it step by step and try to understand it. Thank you, dear Sir. Have a good day. :)

Comment: That was exactly my intention. So that you learn. Especially if you want to learn the solutions without using a for loop. Of course, as with any programming task, it can also be done in many ways. I personally prefer the following scheme `group_by%>% nest%>% mutate (map)%>% unnest`. It is very efficient, elegant, and once you learn it, it will also be very simple and clear. It is also the solution proposed by Hadley Wickham in his book R for Data Science in [Chapter 25](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html). Of course, in the end, you decide which solution suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  rownames_to_column("var") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -var) %>%
  mutate(grp = ifelse(grepl("r", var), "x", "y")) %>%
  group_split(grp) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "name") %>%
  nest(data = -var.x) %>%
  mutate(reg = map_dbl(data, ~glm(value.x ~ value.y, data=.x, family=binomial) %>%
                     summary() %>%
                     coef() %>%
                     .[,2])) %>%
  select(-data)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   var.x       reg
#>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 r1        0.373
#> 2 r2    39436.   
#> 3 r3        0.366
#> 4 r4        0.373
#> 5 r5        0.732
#> 6 r6        0.413
```

First we make your row names into a variable name with `rownames_to_column`, then we take the dataframe from wide to long using `pivot_longer`. Then we split the dataframe based on your "x" variable and your "y" variable for your logistic regression. I then join the split dataframe with itself to get every combination of x and y. Lastly, I `nest` the dataframe and run all the regressions for each "row".

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I am checking it and get back to you shortly. Thank you for your help